# Is it possible to exploit the following code?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I tried to exploit the following code but without succes. I tried an input of 60 + 1 characters but it didn't work.

CFI using labels is enabled. Stack canaries, non-executable stack and ASLR are disabled. Can you make the program print "You won!\n"? (suppose isAdmin is a global variable instead of a variable defined in main(). Is it still possible to exploit the code?)

```
void g() {
   char buff[60];
   gets(buff);
}

void main() {
   int isAdmin = 1;
   g();
   isAdmin = 0;
   g();
   if (isAdmin) { printf("You won!\n"); }
}
```

Comment: Since the array is not global I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Side note: `void main()` is not legal C (except in stand-alone environments)...

Comment: 61 characters won't do it. You have to go deeper into the `main`'s stack frame to overwrite `isAdmin`. I suggest you use `gdb`/`examine memory` to view your exact stack layout.

Comment: From the Linux man page: `Never use gets()`

Comment: If you add the wrong call, it would be vulnerable.

Comment: `gets` actually has been removed from the standard (since C11)...

Comment: Yes I know, but this is just an exercise for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That simple it won't work!

It first depends on if the stack is growing top down or bottom up. With the latter you won't be able at all to overwrite variables on stack of the calling function, they reside in front of the array.

With the latter (admitted, the far more common variant), you might manage successfully to overwrite the `isAdmin` variable. However, when calling a function, there's quite a bit of data reserved on stack, at very, very least, you'll find the return address there. And that one will be overwritten, too! So your programme would continue, or better: try to continue, at some arbitrary address in memory. The most likely result is a crash of your programme.

So your only realistic chance is inlining the function, e. g. with GCC:

```
inline void g() __attribute__((always_inline));
void g()
{
    char buff[64];
    gets(buff);
}
```

Be aware that this is not portable code, the `__attribute__` annotation is GCC (and clang) specific.

That way, I indeed managed to produce your desired result (still requiring a top down stack!). You might need to provide quite a number of extra bytes, alignment issues might enforce quite some gaps in between the variables. However, depending on how much data you overwrite, you might still produce a crash (possibly before any output is produced).

In any case, you are far in the land of undefined behaviour, so there is absolutely no guarantee that you really get what you want, *anything* might happen instead.

Comment: You're right. But I sense this is just an idealistic exercise on IA-32 with no ASLR and stack protection, in which case it would actually work. You just need to  fill in the right return address to `main()` in the buffer - that won't change if ASLR is down. Then you would just go past that and overwrite `isAdmin` on the stack. Obviously portability was not targeted here ...

Comment: @dragosht Still portability is an issue: If question author uses MSVC, she/he won't be able to compile that.

Comment: @dragosht And how would you want to get that return address from outside? Pretty difficult. Enforcing inlining is much simpler to avoid the return address issue. And with that, I managed to produce desired result on a standard Windows environment (Win7), just needed to make sure to provide enough input to cover the alignment gaps in between the variables...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP strictly runs this on some 32-bit Linux, and compiles his code with no optimization options so that address can easily be retrieved with `gdb`. I think this sort of low level hacking exercise is called a logic bomb. There were plenty of such questions on StackOverflow some time ago ...

Comment: I compiled the code with `gcc -g -o buf buf11.c -m32 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -fno-stack-protector`, I have a sense about where you guys are going to but I'm not able to exploit it, Is it possible to share the payload?
@dragosht Indeed, It is meant to retrieve the address easily from gdb.

Comment: @Berkan I reduced the array size to four characters and still needed to input 25 characters to provoke printing 'you won'. You might need even more surplus characters, depending on how the variables are aligned on stack on your system...

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can exploit it but not with standard input. Basically first isAdmin is pushed to the stack, then when calling g you push 60 bytes and after this again 60 bytes. When you manage to write a 1 in byte 120-124 (sizeof(int = 4)) isAdmin will be 1. When using gets() you can only use Ascii characters. There is no key for entering a 1 and I am not sure how gets behaves in this case.

Comment: What about `g()`'s return address? You're not mentioning that ...

Comment: In addition to the return address: There won't be 60 bytes twice on the stack, before the second 60 bytes are pushed, the previous 60 ones are popped from. On the other hand, alignment requirements might enforce some gaps in between the variables.

Comment: ASCII characters are just numerical values as well, e. g. `a` has value 97. Apart from, there's no guarantee that user's system uses ASCII (most likely, some ASCII compatible, but extended characterset, e. g. utf-8 or CP1252). If you manage to overwrite isAdmin (and to return successfully from g!), then *any* value other than 0 is fine to trigger the if...

Comment: @Aconcagua how would you input the character value 1? There is literally no key for it, since its Start of Header

Comment: There's no need to input exact character value of 1. *Any* value is fine, as long as it is not 0. So 'a' (decimal 97) is fine as well. `if(1012)` will do just exactly the same as `if(1)`.